# How to call beginElement() on a svg animate tag in Angular8

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

I have an animate tag on a svg that has 'begin' set to begin="indefinite" so that the animation does not play automatically. I would like to trigger the animation from a typeScript function in Angular.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-testsvg',
  templateUrl: './testsvg.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testsvg.component.scss']
})
export class TestsvgComponent {
  constructor() {}
  onFadePolly() {
    console.log('onFadePolly');
    document.querySelector('svg-id').beginElement();
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="svg">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="350" height="350" viewBox="0 0 350 350">
        <polygon id="poly" points="220,10 300,210 170,250 123,234" style="fill:red;fill-opacity:0;stroke:black;stroke-width:1">
          <animate id="svg-id" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="4s" from="0" to="1"
          fill="freeze" begin="indefinite"/>
        </polygon>
  </svg>
</div>
<button (click)="onFadePolly()">Fade Me Polly</button>
```

Comment: Your code looks "fine" meaning it should be working from a first glance, what's the problem?

Comment: The beginElement() is underlined and the popup hint says: "Property 'beginElement' does not exist on type 'Element'."

Comment: Well, that's because `querySelector()` always returns an object of type `Element`, typescript cannot know if the returned element is for example a `HTMLDivElement` or a `SVGElement`. You will have to cast it to the right type yourself.